# Sound card driver

Tags: drivers, soundcard

I am running a Ubuntu 16.04 release on my PC. The sound card used to work perfectly, but after I installed *oss4-dev*, and *oss4-base*, typed use *apt autoremove* to remove some packages, my computer can no longer play any sound.
*aplay -l* shows that it can not find the sound card.
Can anyone help me fix this issue?

I have tried to compile and install drivers from the Realtek official site, but errors occur when compiling the source code.